# Removing drastic Sublime Text syntax highlighting on named CSS colours

Tags: css, colors, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext2, color-scheme

CSS has a variety of named colours you can use instead of hex/HSL/RGB values, such as "red", "lightcoral", and "maroon". For some reason, almost every colour scheme available for Sublime Text, including Monokai, highlights these - and specifically the CSS colour keywords, not any old incorrect syntax - in an unbearably awful way. Behold:

[image]

It seems to span across colour schemes:

[image]

What setting - or section of the syntax highlighting files - is causing this? I've had little luck on Google, given how search-proof this problem is.

Edit: The first example is SCSS, the second regular CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `.tmLanguage` syntax definition - the color keywords are being recognized as `invalid.deprecated.color.w3c-non-standard-color-name.css` and are being highlighted as such. You'll either have to edit the syntax file to change the scope, or stop using the deprecated color names.

**EDIT**

After reading through the [CSS3 color specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#svg-color), it looks like these color names are now supported by all major browsers, and are no longer deprecated. I updated my `Packages/CSS/CSS.tmLanguage` file and [posted it on Github](https://github.com/MattDMo/sublime-packages/blob/master/CSS/CSS.tmLanguage) for your perusal.

Comment: Above and beyond! Thanks so much - your updated `CSS.tmLanguage` works perfectly. How did you diagnose the keyword recognition, by the way? I'm also adding your revision to my `SCSS.tmLanguage` file; I'll make a pull request to the de facto SCSS package soon.

Comment: You're quite welcome! I use [ScopeHunter](https://github.com/facelessuser/ScopeHunter), which is a bit more user-friendly than the built-in `show_scope_name` command.